# Reading data from a file and inserting into a table using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to insert data into book table by reading data from a txt file, problem is only 1 insert query is generated at the `commit()` statement

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class BookClientFile {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session s1 = sf.openSession();

    BufferedReader br = null;
    Transaction trans = null;

    try {
           br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Books.txt")));
           String line = null;
           String [] row = null;
           Book bk = null;

           trans = s1.beginTransaction();
           while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

               bk = new Book();
               row = line.split(",");

               bk.setBookId(Integer.parseInt(row[0].trim()));
               bk.setTitle(row[1].trim());
               bk.setAuthor(row[2].trim());

               s1.save(bk);
               trans.commit();
           }

    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {

        s1.flush();
        s1.close();

    try {

        if(br != null) {

            br.close();
            br = null;
        }

    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to commit outside the while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the to lines to start transaction for each book.

```
       trans = s1.beginTransaction();
       while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
```

Or move `trans.commit();` out of the while

Comment: same output, the programs halts after generating one sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Take `trans.commit();` out of the while loop.

Comment: nothing is happening , same output `Hibernate: insert into Book (book_title, book_author, book_id) values (?, ?, ?)
`